# ASP.NET MVC jQuery mobile like pages mechanism

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, web-applications, view

To give a more appish experience to my asp.net mvc application, I would like to make the links to other pages (actions in mvc) be loaded using ajax (displaying a loading sign while the request is being processed). I have been quite successful doing this with jQuery Mobile but for the project that I am doing now I prefer not to use it. In part this is because as soon as loading jQuery Mobile css the previous look of the site is disrupted.

Is there a similar page mechanism in asp.net? It would be even better if features such as transitions and pre-rendering of pages would be available too, as jQuery Mobile does.

**An example of what I try to achieve**

I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then on the dashboard view a link:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TaskPage", "List")">LIST</a>
```

Clicking the link would request the list page from the server and start a slide effect to transition from one page to the other.

Thanks for your ideas and knowledge on that!

Comment: What about using [knockoutjs](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) to create a mini spa. The dashboard or the list becomes a partial view that then gets called on a button click event.

Comment: Ok, I can more or less imagine how to implement that. But how would you manage the transition from page to page?

Comment: I am not too sure, but i did use [sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org/) on a vanilla project for navigation. I am not sure how that would be implemented in asp mvc though